# Test Functions Passed as Props to Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a table component which is using `Antd` tables. To highlight a row , I am passing a function :

```
rowClassName={(record, index) => record.id === props.highlightRow ? classes.Highlight : ''}
```

Now my test coverage shows that this line is not covered in testing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp2J7.png)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
it('should highlight row when id matches highlightRow', () => {
  const className = shallow(<YourComponent highLightRow="testId" />).find(Table).prop('rowClassName')({
    id: 'testId'
  });

  expect(className).toBe(classes.Highlight);
});

it('should not highlight row when id does not match highlightRow', () => {
  const className = shallow(<YourComponent highLightRow="newId" />).find(Table).prop('rowClassName')({
    id: 'testId'
  });

  expect(className).not.toBe(classes.Highlight);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way yo test arrow functions, like
`const config = {
            action: (variant, message) => this.action(variant, message),
            message: id ? 'Address updated successfully.' : 'Address added successfully.'
        }`

Comment: The action function shows as not covered in my coverage. Please let me know if there are anythings.

Comment: Arrow functions are not any different to normal functions to test.

So what you need to do in your test is trigger the actual code that would call that `this.action` and then assert on something.

I can't really give more hints without more information and it's really a new question. But i would suggest first learning more about enzyme and how to test a bit more first.

Comment: As part of my coverage, action functuin has full coverage. But where ever im calling it, it shows that code is not covered.